# Can and should I become owner of etc/default/locale?

Tags: command-line, permissions, locale

I want to change my locale from `POSIX` to `en_US.UTF-8`. I know how to change it temporarily in the terminal (by typing: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`) but I want to make it permanent, because I have issues running some of my Python scripts. I have already tried: `$ update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8` but I get an error: `bash: update-locale: command not found`. If there is another command to set my locale, please let me know.

So another way to change my locale should be by editing the file `/etc/default/locale`. I am, however, not the owner of this file (is the root owner?) so I can only read it. I also can't change permissions of this file. The file is empty except for one line which says: `#  File generated by update-locale`. So can/should I become owner of this file and editing this file shouldn't pose any problems, how do I do it?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial on an Acer Chromebook 14 using crouton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `update-locale` command isn't available, your system is severely broken. Maybe the `PATH` variable does not contain all the directories it should.

Anyway, there is no reason to change ownership of `/etc/default/locale`. Try this:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Nope, it did not help. When I type `echo $LANG` I get an empty line as result.

Comment: @HylkevanderVeen: Typing `echo $LANG` is not sufficient to determine if the command succeeded (unless you rebooted first). What does the command `cat /etc/default/locale` output?

Comment: It ouputs `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` finally! I had to reboot my OS for it to work. Also my python files work now. Thanks a lot!